# How to get the selected index number when multiple data in JList is selected

Tags: java, swing, return, jlist

```
    try{
    f = new ProjectFile();

    numProject = f.getOutput();

    String[] projectData = new String[numProject.length];
```

> //retrieving data from another file and store the title to projectData

```
        for (int i = 0; i < projectData.length; i++) {
            projectData[i] = numProject[i].getProjectTitle();
        }

        listProject.setListData(projectData);
        System.out.println(listProject.getSelectedIndex());
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`getSelectedIndices()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndices%28%29) method

```
public int[] getSelectedIndices()

Returns an array of all of the selected indices, in increasing order.
```